# Comparing R and Python Vectorization and Optimization

Tags: python, r, optimization, vectorization

In the **R** language, optimization can be achieved by using `purrr::map()` or `furrr::future_map()` functions. However, I am not sure how does optimization works for [`np.array()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) methods. Indeed, I would like to understand how does **Python** and **R** scales out to parallel processing [1, 2] in terms of complexity and performance.

Thus, the following questions arise:

How does the optimization of [`np.array()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) in **Python** works comparing to `purrr::map()` and `furrr::future_map()` functions in the **R** language?

By doing a simple `tictoc` test on `purrr`/`furrr`, I can observe that we have a big win from vectorization in both cases. Nonetheless, I can also notice that the results seem to show that the **R** language is just fundamentally faster.

## Python

```
import time

a = np.random.rand(1000000)
b = np.random.rand(1000000)

tic = time.time()
c = np.dot(a,b)
toc = time.time()

print ("Vectorized version:" + str(1000*(toc-tic)) +"ms")

c = 0
tic = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
  c += a[i]*b[i]
toc = time.time()

print("For loop:" + str(1000*(toc-tic)) +"ms")
```

### Output

**Vectorized version:** 54.151296615600586ms

**For loop:** 676.0082244873047ms

## R

```
a <- runif(1000000,0,1)
b <- runif(1000000,0,1)

c = 0
tictoc::tic()
c = sum(a * b)
tictoc::toc()

c = 0
tictoc::tic()
  for (i in 1:length(a)) {
    c = a[i]*b[i] + c
  }
tictoc::toc()
```

### Output

**Vectorized version:** 0.013 sec elapsed

**For loop:** 0.065 sec elapsed

## References

[1] Ross Ihaka & Robert Gentleman (1996) R: A Language for Data Analysis and Graphics, Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics, 5:3, 299-314, DOI: [10.1080/10618600.1996.10474713](https://doi.org/10.1080/10618600.1996.10474713)

[2] S. van der Walt, S. C. Colbert and G. Varoquaux, "The NumPy Array: A Structure for Efficient Numerical Computation," in Computing in Science & Engineering, vol. 13, no. 2, pp. 22-30, March-April 2011, doi: [10.1109/MCSE.2011.37](https://doi.org/10.1109/MCSE.2011.37)

Comment: Similar in what way?

Comment: Also, it seems you are sold in using R so why bother using Python at all?

Comment: I have updated my question so that to become more clear. My point is, how can it be similar and different in terms of complexity and performance.

Comment: Yes, I am sold to **R** but still working in **Python** for Machine Learning (ML) projects. Thus, I am stuck to it and would like to know more about how things work.

Comment: Indeed, **Python** remains a great tool for ML projects. Although I am working with a team stuck to **Python**, even for my solo projects **Python** remains my choice.

Comment: Your most recent edits make this question even more broad, when you really should be making it a much more specific question that is on-topic for SO

Comment: You need to only ask one of those questions per post, and I don't know that those individual questions would all be suited to SO anyway. This is the third time it's come up in the reopen queue, and it's still way too broad

Comment: Thanks a lot for reopening my question. Hope this question will be useful for the community.

Comment: If you wan't realisitc measurements use timeit. The real timing for `%timeit np.dot(a,b)` on a not extremely slow cpu should be 0.x ms (depending on the BLAS backend (eg. Intel MKL). You can also include for example a jit compiled function using Numba. (also running in 0.x ms) excluding compilation time (compiled function could be also cached). A simmilar thing should also be done for the R code, which looks to slow for a compiled language (maybe some compilation time is included?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe numpy wraps some of its "primitive" objects in wrapper classes which are, themselves, Python (eg. [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/array_api/_array_object.py) one).
When looking at the R mirror source, I conversely find an [array](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/array.c) class that's basically native code (aka C).
That extra indirection layer alone could explain the difference in speed, I guess.

Comment: Yes, but at what levels of complexity and performance?

Comment: Seems like a 4x speed-up based on that benchmark above (n=1). Running many independent benchmarks will give more data, but 4x seems fair.